# Calling a procedure when we have the name as a string?

Tags: raku

Is it possible to call a procedure in Perl 6 when we have the name as a string?

```
    sub AAA { say "ok"; }
    my $sub = "AAA";
    # &$sub(); or something ?
```

I know that a dispatch table is a better idea:

```
    my %table; %table<a> = &AAA();
    &(%table<a>); # Execute "AAA"
```

I ask because calling a method where we have the name as a string is
possible:

```
    say pi."$_"() for <Int Real Str>;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use indirect name lookup:

```
sub AAA { say "ok"; }
my $sub = "AAA";
&::($sub)();
```